# AngularJS Resource prevent duplicate requests

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

Having pagination on the page I've came across the issue, if the user clicks 3 times on the next page button it will send 3 requests to server. What would be the best solution to prevent it?

I'm using ***angularJs 1.6.6*** with ***ngResource***

Comment: Disable pagination while the request is not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to debounce the button click function. When you debounce a function it will ignore subsequent calls to the function for X seconds.

Lodash comes with a throttle and debounce method for this purpose.

If you dont have lodash available then just go with disabling the button when it is clicked using ng-disabled

Whilst this sorts things client side, it doesn't prevent someone writing some malicious code to hammer you API so some server side protection is a good idea if you have time.

Answer (score 2):

disable the button click till the next page is loaded,
 or [denounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) the click event.